# Function catches exception instead of checking null condition

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, null, stack

I have a function that operates using a Stack. Essentially, it is searching through ArrayLists to find connections between two cities.

For example, if I want to check if there is a connection between Chicago and Jacksonville:

**Format: City : ArrayList of connections**

Chicago : Raleigh, Boston

Raleigh: Dallas, Atlanta

Atlanta: Jacksonville, Tampa

It should return (using it's stack): Chicago, Raleigh, Atlanta, Jacksonville.

Currently, though, it would return: Chicago, Raleigh, Dallas, and then throw a NPE.

Here's the code:

```
    stack.clear();
    if(isDirectPath(originCity,destinationCity)){
        stack.push(originCity);
        stack.push(destinationCity);
        return stack;
    }
    stack = new Stack<City>();

    City topCity, nextCity = null;
    Iterator iter;
    reset(cities);//mark all unvisited
    // get iterator to iterate over the arraylist attached to the origin city
    try
    {
        //get the arraylist(as an iterator) connected to origin city , push it on the stack
        List<City> list1 = (ArrayList) cities.get(originCity.getName());
        originCity.markVisited();
        iter = list1.iterator();
        stack.push(originCity);

        // store the top city on the stack in topCity
        topCity = stack.peek();
        // search cityList

        // examines all the cities connected to topCity until destination city is found (or not!)
        while(!stack.isEmpty() && !topCity.equals(destinationCity))
        {
            // nextcity method traveres the arraylist look for first unvisited city

            if((nextCity = getNextCity(iter)) == null)// no more unvisited cities connect to topCity
            { //so if there are no more unvisited cities connected to topCity,
                // pop stack and store the next  city on the stack in topCity
                stack.pop();
                if (!stack.isEmpty())
                    topCity = stack.peek(); }// close if nextCity
            else // there is another city connected to topCity that is unvisited
            {
                nextCity.markVisited(); // mark it as visited

                //if the city is not already on the stack, store it on the stack and in topCity
                if (!stack.contains(nextCity))
                {
                    stack.push(nextCity);
                    System.out.println(nextCity);
                    topCity = nextCity;
                }
                else // the city is already on the stack, so get another topCity from the stack
                {
                    stack.pop();
                    topCity = stack.peek();
                }
            } // close outer else
            // get arraylist connected to topCity
            list1 = (ArrayList) cities.get(topCity.getName());

            iter = list1.iterator();
        }// close while
    }

    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("city Not Found: ") ; // !!FILE_NOT_FOUND
    }
    return stack; //An empty stack indicates no connections

}  // end isPath
```

What seems to be happening is that, at the following line...

```
if((nextCity = getNextCity(iter)) == null)
```

The function fails to check the null condition, and instead just catches the exception. This causes the stack to return as-is, instead of properly executing the way it was intended to.

I'm not even sure if this is what's happening, but it's my best guess. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Here is the getNextCity function:

```
public City getNextCity(Iterator iter )
{
    City nextCity = null;

    // determines if there are more cities to process and return null if not
    // if there are more cities, gets the next city. If this city is already visited,
    // returns null, otherwise returns next city
    while(iter.hasNext() && (nextCity=(City)iter.next()).hasBeenVisited());
    return nextCity;
}
```

Here is the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FlightMap.isPath(FlightMap.java:185)
    at ControlPanel$ActionHandler.actionPerformed(ControlPanel.java:265)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
city Not Found: 
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4bc6c86
```

Line 185 is `iter = list1.iterator();`
ControlPanel error is just a call to the function.

Comment: you can't doubt java for null check, problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: stack trace would be great..

Comment: Where is your `try` statement?

Comment: Please post code for method getNextCity(iter) and provide detailed information for the NullPointerException

Comment: Post your error stack trace too, please.

Comment: What does `getNextCity` do?  May we see the code?

Comment: Sorry, guys. I've added the code for getNextCity and the stack trace for the NPE.